# Unable to display network image

Tags: flutter, urlencode

I am trying to display image using Network Image but getting the following error:

> ```
> my_domain_name%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B.blob.core.windows.net
> ```
>
> is not a valid link-local address but contains %. Scope id should be
> used as part of link-local address. (at character 23)
> easyentrysystemstorage%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B.blob.co...

I have tried to decode it with following code but still getting error:

```
var encoded = Uri.encodeFull(userProfile.imagePath);
  var decoded = Uri.decodeFull(encoded);
  return Container(
    alignment: Alignment.center,
    child: Container(
      width: 140.0,
      height: 140.0,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
          image: DecorationImage(
              image: NetworkImage(
                decoded,
              ), fit: BoxFit.cover)
      ),
    ),
  );
```

Although the same URL works in the browser it is not working even after encoding and decoding.

Comment: what is the image link?

Comment: image url: https://my_secret_domain.blob.core.windows.net/undefineda359e571-f510-48cc-8cc3-5ae2e473838e/profile.jpg?sv=2019-12-12&st=2020-10-12T13%3A27%3A38Z&se=2020-10-12T15%3A57%3A38Z&sr=b&sp=racwd&sig=%2F3JIeK7qSStPrLXgvKC7NMxwUGfGiHV%2FzxkaXhBvqwo%3D

Comment: Hi, @VisakhVijayan I have shared the link but for security purposes, I have removed the domain.

Answer (score 0):

You should use only decode:

```
var decoded = Uri.decodeFull(userProfile.imagePath);
```

from:

```
my_domain_name%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B.blob.core.windows.net
```

to:

```
my_domain_name​​​​​.blob.core.windows.net
```

Comment: Invalid argument(s): Illegal percent encoding in URI

Comment: Hi, I get the above error when I do only decoding as suggested by you.

Comment: Where are you getting this URL? Some of the percent encodings are not allowed. You should remove before calling "decodeFull", they are not useful.

Comment: It is from our backend build in node and hosted on azure. Can you suggest the encodings that I should remove? I can remove it with the replace function.

Comment: All these: "%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B" consider removing every single percent encoding "%E2" "%80" "%8B"